# How to request for "PUT" in rails with coffeescript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I'm struggling to resolve this particular case.

At first, i prepared this link that users can click

```
<%= link_to 'DOING', task_path(task_todo, new_status: Settings.task_status[:doing]), :method => :put %>
```

Secondly, i wanted this to be linked with table row,
so wrote like this.

```
<% @tasks_todo.each do |task_todo| %>
    <tr data-link="<%= task_path(task_todo, new_status: Settings.task_status[:doing])%>">
        <td><%= @projects.find(task_todo.project_id).project_name %></td>
        <td><%= task_todo.task_name %></td>
        <td><%= task_todo.memo %></td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

And coffeescript is like this.

```
$ ->
  $(document).on('click', 'tr[data-link]', (evt) -> 
    window.location = this.dataset.link
)
```

Now i could make this row clickable, but method is still 'GET', so it went wrong "Controller#Action". How could i make it as 'PUT'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`link_to ... method: :put` does a bit of JavaScript magic. You cannot make a PUT request using `window.location`. There are only two ways to make a PUT request:

- Without transition: AJAX
- With a transition: submitting a form.

Basically, to recreate what Rails is doing for you, what you would need to do is to create a form element, put some input elements into it, then call `.submit()` on the form.

Comment: Thank you. Finally, i took a work around by adding new route as 'GET', because i'm not good at javascript and AJAX...